# display the repeated author's name in the bibliography using IEEE style

Tags: natbib, ieeetran, author, ieee-style, bibliographystyle

how to display the same author's name in the bibliography using IEEE style instead of dash/ditto (---) at the repeated author.

I'm using

```
\usepackage[numbers,compress]{natbib}
```

and

```
\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran} \bibliography{references}
```

Answer (score 1):

As shown in `"C:\texlive\2023\texmf-dist\doc\latex\ieeetran\bare_adv.tex"`, you should use `cite` not `natbib`.

`reference.bib`

```
@IEEEtranBSTCTL{BSTcontrol,
CTLdash_repeated_names = "no",
}
@article{A,author={tim},title={A}}
@article{B,author={tim},title={B}}
```

```latex
\documentclass{IEEEtran}
\usepackage[noadjust]{cite}
\begin{document}
\bstctlcite{BSTcontrol}
\cite{A}\cite{B}
\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}
\bibliography{reference}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: there is an error `undefined control sequence \bstctlcite` when I run the program @clara

Comment: I'm using the journal template's documentclass

Comment: `\bstctlcite` is defined in `C:\texlive\2023\texmf-dist\tex\latex\ieeetran\IEEEtran.cls`.

Comment: I've found the IEEEtran.cls 's file, but I can not find the \bstctlcite inside the cls file .. sorry I don't really understand .. @clara

Comment: What is your version of `IEEEtran.cls`? `\ProvidesClass{IEEEtran}[2015/08/26 V1.8b by Michael Shell]`.

Comment: IEEEtran.cls 2012/12/27 version V1.8 by Michael Shell @clara

Comment: What is your LaTeX distribution? I think you should use a new one, such as TeX Live 2023.